# python ctypes, call user32 and kernel32 func with arguments

Tags: python, ctypes

I need to know how many arguments to pass in user32 and kernel32 functions
for example :

```
windll.kernel32.GetConsoleTitle()
```

I get Error :

> :ValueError: Procedure probably called with not enough arguments (4 bytes missing)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking sufficient detail to help the community help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the API decscription. Here's the link for GetConsoleTitle:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsoletitle

```
DWORD WINAPI GetConsoleTitle(
  _Out_ LPTSTR lpConsoleTitle,
  _In_  DWORD  nSize
);
```

*Update:*
Here's a short demo of getting console window title:

```
import ctypes
MAX_BUFFER = 260
title_text_buffer = (ctypes.c_char * MAX_BUFFER)()
res = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleTitleA(title_text_buffer, MAX_BUFFER)
title_text = title_text_buffer.value
print title_text
```

Comment: thank you @ababak, and where can i find  other functions docs example user32, shell32 to learn it?

Comment: The link I've provided in my answer has other functions listed as well.

Answer (score 1):

Tiny update to above code:

```
>>> import ctypes

>>> MAX_LEN = 256
>>> buffer_ = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(MAX_LEN)
>>> ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleTitleW(buffer_, MAX_LEN)
5
>>> buffer_.value
'Command Prompt - python'
```